# How to find element of a grid to insert data in it using Selenium with C#?

Tags: html, css, selenium, katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

I have tried 'Inspect Element', Firebug, FirePath, Selenium IDE, Katalon Recorder to find element. But it is not working when I use this Css/xPath in my code. I need to automate the newly added row scenario. The first element of the grid is a drop down and after selecting value from it the second element, which is also a dropdown, populates. The Css/xPath for the first element while inspecting the required value is:

**Css:** `body > div.k-animation-container > div > div.k-list-scroller > ul > li:nth-child(35)`

**xPath:** `.//*[@id='ng-app']/body/div[4]/div/ul/li[35]`

[Here is my the sample html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXFwF.png), I need to select the value from the drop-down.

What should I do to fix this so that the code always able to select the value from the drop-down?

Comment: Please share more of the HTML. And by what criteria are you choosing the value?

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath (I'm presupposing you want to select the element containing text "AEP Public Service of Oklahoma")

```
.//*[@id='ng-app']/body/div[4]/div/ul/li[contains(.,'AEP Public Service of Oklahoma')]
```